# Convert a datetime column (currently of type nvarchar) to user-defined datetime format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, format

In my SQL Server database table, I have a `nvarchar` column with values such as 'Thursday, 29 - September - 2022, 11:44 pm'.

I want to convert this to 'DD/MM/YY' format:

```
SELECT FORMAT ('Thursday, 29 - September - 2022, 11:44 pm', 'dd/MM/yy') AS date
```

and I'm expecting the result in `DD/MM/YY` format, but I'm not getting the proper output.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract dd mmm and yyyy using substring first and then you can append those to be able to convert to date stype 106. After you have date object you can get any desired format.

Try following:

```
select CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME, 
               
               Substring(str, CHARINDEX(', ', str)+2, 2) + ' ' +  
               Substring(
  left(str, len(str) - CHARINDEX('-', reverse(str)) - 1), CHARINDEX('-', str) + 2, 
  len(left(str, len(str) - CHARINDEX('-', reverse(str)) - 1)) - CHARINDEX('-', str))
               + ' ' +
               Substring(str, len(str) - CHARINDEX('-', reverse(str)) + 3, 4)
               , 106), 3) 
  from (values ('Sun, 25 - May - 2022, 05:00 pm')) v(str)
```

Created a fiddle for demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/apcal_Ca